# How do I set case for tar, gz and tar.gz files?

Tags: bash, gzip, tar

I have few files in a directory like this:

```
xxx.tar.gz
xxx.tar
yyy.tar.gz
yyy.tar
zzz.txt.gz
...
...
```

I have list.txt for files like this:

list.txt:

```
/home/phe/xxx.tar.gz
/home/phe/xxx.tar
/home/phe/yyy.tar.gz
/home/phe/yyy.tar
/home/phe/zzz.txt.gz
...
...
```

I need to extract these files like this:

```
for file in (cat list.txt); do
   tar zxvf $file
done
```

How can I open tar.gz, txt.gz and tar files in same command?

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: `while read -r file; do [ "${file##*.}" = "gz" ] && tar -xvzf "$file"; done <list.txt` maybe?

Comment: tar -zxvf getting error for .tar and .gz files.

Comment: See the updated comment -- Never mind I see the .txt now, Hold on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like that:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
    file="${file##*/}" # remove the directory
    case $file in
        *.tar.gz)
            tar xzvf "$file"
            ;;
        *.txt.gz)
            gzip -d "$file"
            ;;
    esac
done < list.txt
```

Note that for the `tar` command I suspect you would need to specify some output directory with `-C` because otherwise everything will be extracted in the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm reading your question right and the `.txt.gz` files are just gzipped, the `.tar.gz` files are tarballs, and the `.tar` files are simply tar archives, without compression, then you could do something like the following:

```
while read -r file; do 
    tmp = "${file##*/}"
    [ "${tmp:3:3}" = "txt" ] && gzip -dk "$file"  ## remove k to delete original
    [ "${tmp##.}" = "tar" ] && tar -xvf "$file"
    [ "${tmp##.}" = "gz" ] && tar -xvzf "$file"
done <list.txt
```

If the files are no longer in their original directories (as shown in the `list.txt` file), change `tmp` to `file` above.

Comment: Please fix your errors! (and use more idiomatic bash too).

Comment: What were they and what is non-idiomatic about the portable script above?

Comment: Did you even try your script? `tmp = "${file##*/}"`: spaces around `=`? seriously? `${tmp:3:3}`: do you even know what that does? certainly not what you need here; and hey! it's not even portable. How about `${tmp##.}`? do you really think `tmp` has a leading `.`? and if it were the case, you wouldn't use `##` but `#`. Why do you even need the `tmp` variable? why don't you just use a portable `case` statement?

Comment: Regarding idioms: in Bash, to check whether a string ends with e.g., `.txt`, you'd use a glob like `[[ $string = *.txt ]]`.

Comment: The spaces issue was an obvious oversight, it's challenging to practice law while helping with shell scripting at the same time `:)` As for as the `[[`, if there is a feature where the bashism is required, (e.g. `=~`), I use `[[`, otherwise, where there is a POSIX portable way to write the expression, that is what I prefer.